# What is a Mono Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Mono Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Mono Words | Not Mono Words |
| --- | --- |
| VERB | NOUN |
| SALON | SALOON |
| MENTAT | MENTAL |
| BREW | DREW |
| NUMB | NAME |
| ALM | ALMA MATER |
| JUDGE | JUDGED |
| ARK | LARK |
| LOSS | LOSE |
| LEMON | MELON |

Text version:

```
Mono Words,Not Mono Words
VERB,NOUN
SALON,SALOON
MENTAT,MENTAL
BREW,DREW
NUMB,NAME
ALM,ALMA MATER
JUDGE,JUDGED
ARK,LARK
LOSS,LOSE
LEMON,MELON
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mono words:

> Can be found in the names of books of the Bible.

Thus:

> VERB in PRO**VERB**S
>  SALON in 1&2 THES**SALON**IANS
>  MENTAT in LA**MENTAT**IONS
>  BREW in HE**BREW**S
>  NUMB in **NUMB**ERS
>  ALM in PS**ALM**S
>  JUDGE in **JUDGE**S
>  ARK in M**ARK**
>  LOSS in CO**LOSS**IANS
>  LEMON in PHI**LEMON**

As for the name:

> Possibly because Christianity is a MONOtheistic religion? Or because of SONG OF SOLOMONOMONOMON... ;-)

Comment: Perfecto :) Mono for monotheistic.